# ORDER BY / OFFSET on Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

It looks like Azure SQL data warehouse doesn't support the OFFSET statement (as part of ORDER BY).  I'm curious at to what is the best way to get paginated data out of Azure-DW?